# sencha touch, sync() desn't set dirty flag to false after success

Tags: extjs, touch, store

here is my code:

In the controller i set a value in an existing record:

```
this.record.set('description', 'test');        
this.getFlightsList().getStore().sync();
```

And then i call the sync() explicitly.
I can see the right call to the server with 1 object

```
{id: 1, description: 'test'}
```

and the correct response:

```
{"message":"success","data":[],"returnCode":0,"success":true}
```

But, if I try to edit another record, every time, it sends also the last modified record so it sends an object with 2 distinct records, the current and the last one.

```
   [ {id: 1, description: 'test'}, {id: 2, description: 'test2'}]
```

and so on.

In fact if I analyze the store, I see the property `dirty: true` on the last record (id:1), but it should be false after the sync() success. (?!)

Any ideas?

Could it be that I have to put the modified data in the response? Such as:

```
{"message":"success","data":[{id:1, description:'test'}],"returnCode":0,"success":true}
```

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

sync() is an asynchronous function. Try checking your record in callback:

```
this.getFlightsList().getStore().sync({
    callback: function (batch) {

        console.log(batch.operations);// your sync'ed records 

    }
});
```